# Android studio: App crashing on Yahoo Weather API

Tags: java, api, crash, yahoo, weather

App crashes on this instruction:

```
String endpoint = String.format("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json", Uri.encode(YQL));
```

anything wrong with it?

Comment: says format string is malformed...

Comment: changed the url to
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="nome,
ak")&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

Comment: now it doesnt crash but my info doesnt show in the view... Is it a problem with the view or the link??